# Nextjs new slug page from cms strapi get 404 error

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, strapi, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a site written in nextjs + cms stripi. There is a product catalog on the site, and when I add a new product, it appears in the list of products with all the necessary attributes, but when I follow the link to this product, I get a 404. In development mode, everything works fine, but I get an error on the server.

blank/[slug].js

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const blanksRes = await fetchAPI("/blanks", { fields: ["slug"] });

  return {
    paths: blanksRes.data.map((blank) => ({
      params: {
        slug: blank.attributes.slug,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const blanksRes = await fetchAPI("/blanks", {
    filters: {
      slug: params.slug,
    },
    populate: ["*", "slug"],
  });

  return {
    props: {
      blank: blanksRes.data[0],
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

Card component:

```
const Card = ({ blank }) => {
<Link
   key={blank.id}
   href={`/blank/${blank.attributes.slug}`}
>
...
</Link>
```

next.config.js :
`output: "standalone"`

http://172.17.0.5:1337 - my forward strapi IP on the server

```
export function getStrapiURL(path = "") {
  return `${
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL || "http://172.17.0.5:1337"
  }${path}`;
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production

FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build --force

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_SHARP_PATH=/tmp/node_modules/sharp

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 80

ENV PORT 80

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

It seems that next js does not see the page after the build. If you make a build and upload to the server, then the page will be displayed. Strapi is located on the subdomain strapi.domainname.com , ssl certificate is installed. Tried to change localhost url to real localhost ip: localhost:1338 to 172.17.0.5:1337